# How to make a password uncrackable for one username "System"

Tags: security

I am working on an old website and trying to make it reach today's web standards. The website contains many database tables with over 1 million rows in some of them. The website does not have a user system: I deleted the user database table today. It had 10k users, which are all gone now. Because of the insecurity and the way of information is stored - yes my OCD kicked in!), and I am currently making a new table for users and store passwords in the right way! Not by using `md5()`! 
For the data that was added to the website before.. I would like to create a user account called "System". This is the default user that will show for the old data that was added to the website. How can I make this account inaccessible!? what should I be putting for the password in the database so that no one can crack it (cracking it should be hard anyways because of the `password_hash()` function)!

Should I put a value that is shorter than my `password_hash()` function.. will that make the account inaccessible on the website? drawbacks of why I should not do this?
OR
Should I make a password that is complicated too the point that I won't remember it?

One last thing, CONSIDER answering before you click THAT button.

Comment: I think your question is mostly centered about security, so it may be better suited for http://security.stackexchange.com/ . A good rule of thumb might be that there is no code involved with the issue at hand. I would also argue that this is not a PHP issue per se.

Comment: A simple `NULL` value or `"-"` in place of an actual hash will never verify with `password_verify`. - Or which specific issues did you run in when testing either of your ideas?

Comment: @mario Did not run into any issue. I am just asking and see if there is any good reasoning of why I should use a "given" method. You put your answer in a comment are you scared of people using The Button on you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few options:

1. Add an `active` column to the database

   You would check that column on login. So that way you can have accounts that are still represented, but are not active (and hence can't authenticate as them).

   If this is the only account you're ever doing this with, it may be overkill.
2. Empty the `password` hash column

   Then, when trying to `password_verify()` against the empty hash, it would simply fail.

   You *could* make a random password, but why bother?

   One note: be **sure** to make an exception in the password reset functionality to not allow reset of the system account.

Answer (score 1):

I think best way is add to user table column `banned`, for example and set it for user system to true. In your auth script you can check value of this column.